# What's a good way to get c information?

Tags: c, reference

What I mean by this question is unlike other programming languages where I could simply just google the phrase "implementing comparable interfaces java" or "graphics drawing python", whenever I google a C problem, it seems that the majority of the results are about C# or C++

I've tried saying ANSI C or C99 instead but that's not too successful. I lent my friend in college my K&R C bible, is there any websites that are good definitive c sources?

Comment: A lot of C/C++ is similar- what specifically C topic are you interested in?

Comment: Im sure there are, I just googled "ANSI C" and it came up with a whole bunch.  What exactly are you wanting to reference?

Comment: My internship is working on the ffmpeg project which was written in c, but I'm trying to remember all sorts of things about c so really it's general reference

Comment: @DavidB: Only where it doesn't matter. That attitude can be dangerous, especially for beginners!

Comment: [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) is primarily C++, but it do have sections on [null-terminated strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte) as well as [C-style I/O](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c), and most of the basic language constructs/operators/statements and basic types are the same in both C and C++.

Comment: @bitmask do you reccomend not reading too much into the C++ references then?

Comment: @bitmask I'd say the attitude is least dangerous for beginners. They can go ahead and throw around C++ strings willy nilly- it's the advanced programmers that think like this that are a problem.

Comment: @SetSlapShot: Yes and no. If you want to do C++, do/read C++. If you want to do C, do/read C. My personal opinion is that you should mentally regard these as completely different things, because (although they have similar syntactic parts) they are (or should be) used completely in a different way. At any rate, if you're looking for C help, any reference that contains C++ will be of zero use to you.

Comment: Stackoverflow.com is a good place to get all information you want. The only way to get information is searching with a C tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.cprogramming.com/

Also that K & R C book is available as a pdf :)

Comment: This is an awesome list too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: And if you're doing low-level POSIX stuff on Unix, then the best resource is man pages.

Answer (score 2):

What seems to work well for me is to put what I am looking for and follow it with " in c programming"

so if I wanted info on using structs in c i would put "structs in c programming"

Answer (score 2):

I have a good C reference book called C Programming FAQ. I found a [similar website](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi) that helps tackle most of the common problems.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get a good grasp as how OO works, you can transfer algorithms and patterns to C easily.

Also, currently the best C referente IMHO is StackOverflow.com.

Comment: @SetSlapShot and you can search StackOverflow by tags to get only c-related questions :)